# Why won't my libvirt VM communicate with apt repositories when wget and ping work?

Tags: virtualization, apt, libvirt

I'm trying to use Vagrant and Puppet to make it easier to duplicate a multi-server setup for our websites. The recommended workflow is to `vagrant up` the puppetmaster server specifically first, and then use it to provision the rest of the servers. So, I'm running this shell script on the master:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

if [ "$EUID" -ne "0" ] ; then
    echo "Script must be run as root." >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ -e /etc/init.d/puppetmaster ] ; then
    echo "Puppetmaster is already installed."
    exit 0
fi

echo "Installing Puppet repo for Debian Wheezy"
wget -qO /tmp/puppetlabs-release-wheezy.deb \
    https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-wheezy.deb

dpkg -i /tmp/puppetlabs-release-wheezy.deb
rm /tmp/puppetlabs-release-wheezy.deb
aptitude update
echo Installing Puppetmaster.
aptitude install -y puppetmaster facter
echo "Puppet installed!"
cp /tmp/puppet.conf /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
puppet resource package hiera ensure=installed
echo "Hiera installed!"
cp /tmp/hiera.yaml /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
```

My box is baremettle/debian-7.5.

Vagrantfile:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # Supports local cache, don't waste bandwidth.
    # Do `vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier`
    # https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
        config.cache.auto_detect = true
        config.cache.scope = :box
    end

    # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
    # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
    # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

    # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
    config.vm.box = "baremettle/debian-7.5"

    config.vm.provider :libvirt do |lv|
        lv.driver = 'kvm'
        lv.connect_via_ssh = false
        lv.storage_pool_name = 'default'
    end

    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

    config.vm.define :memcache, primary: true do |mem|
        mem.vm.hostname = "memcache.local"
        mem.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.122.20"

        mem.vm.provider :libvirt do |lv|
            lv.memory = 1024
        end

        mem.vm.provision :file, source: "master/puppet.conf", destination: "/tmp/puppet.conf"
        mem.vm.provision :file, source: "master/hiera.yaml", destination: "/tmp/hiera.yaml"
        mem.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
        mem.vm.provision :puppet, module_path: "master/modules", manifests_path: "master/manifests", manifest_file: "default.pp"
        mem.vm.provision :puppet_server do |puppet|
            puppet.options = '--verbose --waitforcert 30'
            puppet.puppet_server = "memcache.local"
        end
        mem.vm.synced_folder "puppet/manifests", "/etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests", type: 'nfs'
        mem.vm.synced_folder "puppet/modules", "/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules", type: 'nfs'
        mem.vm.synced_folder "master/hieradata", "/etc/puppet/environments/production/hieradata", type: 'nfs'
    end
end
```

Now, the problem occurs when `aptitude update` runs. It just sits there without any error message. No CPU usage from the process. No timeout ever happens, not even the 0% start of the progress.

That sounds like a firewall problem, but downloading the .deb with wget works. I can ping mirrors.kernel.org, which is the repo listed in sources.list. If I really wanted to, I'm sure I could find the right package files and download them manually, but no one wants to do that.

`vagrant ssh` works fine, if I interrupt the `up` command first. Doing `sudo apt-get update` or `install` does the same thing.

What could be wrong? I don't know what else to check. Does APT use some weird variant of HTTP that's hitting my firewall? I know this used to work when I last looked at this project last year.

Vitals:

- x86_64
- Linux Mint 17 (host)
- Debian Wheezy 7.5 (guest)
- Vagrant 1.6.5
- libvirt0 1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.6
- vagrant-libvirt plugin 0.0.24